# jQuery In Action Second Edition code examples don't work

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently purchased [jQuery In Action Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/bibeault2/), and I was going through the [sample source code](http://www.manning.com/bibeault2/jqia2.source.zip)(warning: zip file) downloaded from the website.

When I open the 'jQuery Selectors Lab' example page from Chapter 2, I don't see any images or DOM content in Chrome or in Firefox. In the Chrome developer tools console I see the following error message:

[image: Chrome console error message]

Has anybody come across this issue before? How do I resolve it?

Comment: what it says, load the file from a webserver instead of loading it from disk and it will work.  No idea what's the easiest way to get a webserver running on your mac but pretty sure there are simple ways to get one quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a software as [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) and load your files into the httpd folder of the app. Then call your script using the URL localhost/yourscript. It should work :)

Comment: Because you are using AJAX, it won't work without a server giving proper responses like 200 - OK

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the *command line* and have either **python** or **ruby**, you can just run one of the following commands in the folder directory to start a local server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

or

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8000
```

From there, just enter in the browser: `http://localhost:8000` and you are good to go.